# Why is there no makaf between “Ben” and “Yair”?

Tags: sources-mekorot, megillat-esther

Second chapter, fifth passuk of Megillat Esther reads:

> אִ֣ישׁ יְהוּדִ֔י הָיָ֖ה בְּשׁוּשַׁ֣ן הַבִּירָ֑ה וּשְׁמ֣וֹ מָרְדֳּכַ֗י **בֶּ֣ן יָאִ֧יר** בֶּן־שִׁמְעִ֛י בֶּן־קִ֖ישׁ אִ֥ישׁ יְמִינִֽי׃
>
> In the fortress Shushan lived a Jew by the name of Mordecai, son of Jair son of Shimei son of Kish, a Benjaminite.

We see makafs (hyphens) by the two later mentioned predecessors but not between “ben” and “Yair”, why is it not present like the latter two?

Comment: I dared to edit your transliteration, please roll back if you don't like it.

Comment: The simple answer is because there is a n'gina under it. A 'dargo' always   comes with one before it.

Comment: @interested that's not an answer, but a description. Why is there a negina and not a makaf?

Comment: @DoubleAA Look at it the other way round. Why must they have a makaf. Because they must. Whereas the first doesnt need one so it can have a negina. At least the second one must have, so also the third has but the first doesnt need to have.

Comment: Why does the second one must have? @interested you're still just describing not explaining

Comment: If I said that there are 7 exceptions to the rule, and this is one of them, would you accept it as an answer?

Comment: @DoubleAA what negina would you then choose for the second one and the word after it, remember after a dargo there has to be a tvir, so shimi would be 'lost'

Comment: @interested the second Ben would get a merkha (like any small word before tvir) and the darga would become a kadma. If there were no makafs we could fill in the neginos without a problem. They'd be different, surely, but they could have the same grammatical pauses. So what?

Comment: (incidentally in rare cases there can be a merkha between a darga and a tvir https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%92_%D7%94 but that wouldn't apply here)

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact that Moredicha was the son of Yair but Yair was not the son of Shmi...

Comment: Meaning a true ben no makaf, not true son has makaf

Comment: @sam Here they only seem to suggest symbolic meaning: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Midrash_Lekach_Tov_on_Esther.2.5.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: That's a gemara I believe as well,but in reality he was a son on Yair,the question is why mention everyone else who aren't literal grandfathers